# Django query: get value from not directly related model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to get value from not directly related model in Django.
I have following models:

```
class Platform(models.Model):
    platform = models.CharField()


class Game(models.Model):
    game = models.CharField()
    genre = models.CharField()


class Link(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform)
```

How could I get QuerySet of Game objects where game title (Game.game field) would be replaced to following pattern: Game (Platform) (eg. 'Battlefield (PS3)') without extra hits to database?

In SQL it would look like this:

```
SELECT
  g.id,
  g.game || ' (' || p.platform || ')' AS game
FROM game g INNER JOIN link l ON g.id = l.game_id
  LEFT JOIN platform p ON l.platform_id = p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use link_set to get the reverse lookup for games here's the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

```
class Platform(models.Model):
    platform = models.CharField()


class Game(models.Model):
    game = models.CharField()
    genre = models.CharField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = "{0} ({1})".format(self.title, self.link__platform)
        super(Game, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Link(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('game', 'platform')
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need only one related platform name for each Game object: eg. 2 items in QuerySet:
`Battlefield (PS3), Battlefield (PC)` — **not** `Battlefield (PS3, PC)`. How could I connect them?

Comment: Well then you need to make you link model unique_together and unless you plan on adding extra fields to link you may as well just add a foreign key on the game model, I'll update my answer based on wether you are having extra fields on the link model?